# How can I tumble at 30m in Ski Safari 2?

Tags: achievements, android, ski-safari

One of the achievements in the Twisted Canyon stage in Ski Safari 2 is "Tumble at 30m" and I've not been able to crack it.

What's the trick? I've tried crashing right before the edge of a steep cliff but the progress bar for the achievement jumps back and forth as I drop.